# CodeRush' XPress solution cache getting a bit big (4.5Gb)

Tags: devexpress, visual-studio-2008-sp1, coderush-xpress

...any ideas how to stop it from growing?

Our IT services has placed a cap on profile size anmd now we're getting annoying audit messages.

Normally I'd blame IT servcies for their 'One size fits all, treating developers like they were drones from sector 7G' attitude but 4.5GB is a bit on the big size.

Give how clever those chaps at DevExpress are I can't believe they've implemented this caching without a setting to keep it from growing so large.

Have we missed something?

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty I think you'd be better off asking DevExpress directly.

Try the Support Center ( http://www.devexpress.com/sc/ ) 
Or email them direct support@devexpress.com

That said... even if the cache isn't self regulating, you should be able to blow away the SolutionCache and AssemblyCache folders without any major issues... The caches in question will be rebuild as needed.

Comment: Turns out the cahce isn't self-regulating but it can be pointed at another location to avoid bloating the profile (although why develeopers should have the roaming profile switched on is beyond me).